# sizing of contained view controller in iOS clipping 91 pixels

Tags: ios, ios6

I am experimenting with a contained view controller but am having problems with even the simplest form. Basically, it is cutting off the bottom 90 pixels and I am not sure why.

I have included my code and a screenshot with a similarly sized UIView next to it. This 90 pixel `clipping` consistent across different sized (ie if the height is made 200px, then it shows as 110 pixels). Any help would be appreciated as this has become very frustrating. Why is it being sized at this size and how do I fix?

thx in advance

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  // this is the left one below that is the problem
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.myView=[[JtViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"JtViewController" bundle:nil];
   self.myView.view.frame=CGRectMake(10.0f,10.0f,100.0f,100.0f);
   self.myView.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
   [self addChildViewController:self.myView];                 // 1
   [self.view addSubview:self.myView.view];
   [self.myView didMoveToParentViewController:self.myView];          // 3


   // this one is ok
   self.testView=[[UIView alloc] init];
   self.testView.frame=CGRectMake(150.0f,10.0f,100.0f,100.0f);
   self.testView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
   [self.view addSubview:self.testView];
```

[image]

**edit 1**

I've updated the code so the first 4 comments are effectively irrelevant

**edit 2**

```
@implementation JtViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: What's the frame of the containing view controller? i.e. the view controller whose `viewDidLoad` you showed.

Comment: Let me look into that; it's probably not what I'm understanding. Shouldn't addSubview be handling that though?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and I got a 200x200 blue view. Do you have any view in the controller where this code is except for the full screen self.view?

Comment: so if I delete out the xib file and initWithNibName -> just init, it works ok. Hmm.... not sure what is going on as that isn't what I'd exepect

Comment: What is the `JtViewController` you're using here? Can you paste in relevant source code?

Comment: Can we see the nib? it would appear that could be the problem if just `init` works.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's the answer I posted below. If you want to add more info on why this is, I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the common mistake to setup subview's bounds in **- (void)viewDidLoad**

> *- (void)viewDidLoad;*
>   This is an exceptionally good place to put a lot of setup code.
>   But be careful because the geometry of your view (its bounds) is not set yet.
>   If you need to initialize something based on the geometry of the view, use the *- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;* method
>
> *- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;*
>   When this is called, your bounds has been set (via your frame by your superview or some such). Your view will probably only get “loaded” once, but it might appear and disappear a lot.
>   So don’t put something in this method that really wants to be in viewDidLoad.
>   Otherwise, you might be doing something over and over unnecessarily.
>   Use this to optimize performance by waiting until this method (i.e. just before view appears) to kick off an expensive operation (might have to put up a spinning “loading” icon though).

For better understanding please refer to [Stanford lecture](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/lectures/Lecture%206.pdf) and Apple doc [Responding to Display-Related Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications.html)

So just move setting subview frame to *- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;* method

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.myView.view.frame=CGRectMake(10.0f,10.0f,100.0f,100.0f);
}
```

**P.S** I've noticed another mistake (maybe it just typo) in line:

```
[self.myView didMoveToParentViewController:self.myView];
```

Should be:

```
[self.myView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: thx - heading on flight now so can't test but this sounds reasonable

Answer (score 1):

I was using Interface Builder.

So the fix seemed to be to delete the window from the contained ViewController and just add a UIView in and set that to the File's Owner's view. Probably learned to never worry about UIWindow but in this case, you have to worry about UIWindow.